# How to test Update method in Java Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I am creating Unit Test for my ServiceImpl methods and I try to create a unit test for `update` method. However, I am not sure how should I test this method. It returns `DTO` of corresponding entity, but I have really no idea if I should use `@Spy` or `@Captor`. If I set a mock variable and then try to retrieve it and update its value, I will need to retrieve the same record to check its updated value.

I am new in testing and I have not found a proper example for update method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public CompanyDTO update(CompanyRequest companyRequest, UUID uuid) {

    final Company company = companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(COMPANY));
    company.setName(companyRequest.getName());
    final Company savedCompany = companyRepository.save(company);
    return new CompanyDTO(savedCompany);
}
```

**Update:** Finally I make it worked, but I am not sure for some parts. Is there anything missing or redundant in the following test method?

```
@InjectMocks
private CompanyServiceImpl companyService;

@Mock
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Company> companyCaptorEntity;    

@Test
public void testUpdate() {
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final CompanyRequest request = new CompanyRequest();
    request.setName("Updated Company Name");

    final Company company = new Company();
    company.setName("Company Name");
    
    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid))
        .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(company));

    //??? Do we need this?
    when(companyRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(company);

    CompanyDTO result = companyService.update(request, uuid);

    Mockito.verify(companyRepository).save(companyCaptor.capture());

    Company savedCompany = companyCaptor.getValue();
    assertEquals(request.getName(), savedCompany.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More importantly than the return type of the `update()` method, I believe you should test the values of the entity passed to the `save()` method of your mock repository (I assume you have one).

For this, you can use `ArgumentCaptor`.

For testing the return logic of your `update()` method, you can simply assign its result in your test to a response object. You can then compare this object with the values of your input object.

Here is an example of both testing the arguments to the save method of your mock repository and the return of your update method (they should be two different unit tests):

```
@Test
void test() {
    // Arrange
    ArgumentCaptor<Entity> entityArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
    InputDto inputDto = prepareTestInput();

    // Act
    ResponseDto responseDto = service.update(inputDto);
    verify(repositoryMock, times(1)).save(entityArgumentCaptor.capture());

    // Assert
    Entity savedEntity = argumentCaptor.getValue();
    assertEquals(input.getVariable1(), savedEntity.getVariable1());
    // .....
    // compare ResponseDto and InputDto too
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations. Could you pls update your answer according to my service method? I have some trouble for some parts :(

Comment: I think it will be more beneficial for you if you try by yourself because you will eventually learn a lot. Let me know if you have any specific questions and I'll help. P.S. Remember to mock the 'companyRepository.findByUuid' to return a Company object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please have a look at my Update and test method?

Comment: You have done it well. About your two questions - no, you don't need an argument captor for the DTO result, because the update() method is already returning it. We are using argument captors in cases where a given object is not being returned from our service method, but is passed to a method of a mock class, so this is a way for us to test that it was passed with correct arguments.

Comment: About your second question regarding the mock of repository.save() - if you don't return a Company object,I believe null will be passed to the constructor of CompanyDTO, where you will likely experience a NullPointerException. You can test by yourself and see.

Comment: I need to be clarify about the following issues... Could you please help me?

Comment: Which issues? I answered the code comments from your updated post already

Comment: **1.** In my test method, I created `request` and `company` variables. Then I set the `companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)` result as `company` that I already set its name property (`company.setName(companyRequest.getName());` line in the `update` method). Then I set `companyRepository.save(company)` to return `company variable`. Finally I call my service method by passing mt captor to the repository and then use this captor to retrieve the result of `companyRepository.save()` method. Is this scenario all true according to the service and test methods above?

Comment: **2.** Do we need to use `result` variable? I think here is we need captor rather than result` variable. Is that true?

Comment: **3.** How `companyCaptor` plays role in `Mockito.verify(companyRepository).save(companyCaptor.capture());`. How can we translate this line? Does `companyCaptor` grabs the return value of that method?

Comment: **4.** I am not sure if I need `ArgumentCaptor` for this scenario. Because I wanted to check the value before and after update, but in this usage I do not check it properly I think.

Comment: Amigo? Any help please? Thanks in advance